# Stacking <div>s horizontally

Tags: html, css

I have setup JsFiddle [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/AJNym/)

```
<div id="fsUploadProgress">
   <div class="progressWrapper" id="SWFUpload_0_2" style="opacity: 1; ">
      <div class="progressContainer blue">
         <a class="progressCancel" href="#" style="visibility: hidden; "> </a>
         <div class="progressName">Photo0144111111111111111.jpg</div>
         <div class="progressBarStatus">Complete.</div>
         <div class="progressBarComplete" style=""></div>
         <div id="SWFUpload_0_2_deleteDiv" class="remove" style="text-align: right; ">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">x</a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="progressWrapper" id="SWFUpload_0_3" style="opacity: 1; ">
      <div class="progressContainer blue">
         <a class="progressCancel" href="#" style="visibility: hidden; "> </a>
         <div class="progressName">Photo0145.jpg</div>
         <div class="progressBarStatus">Complete.</div>
         <div class="progressBarComplete" style=""></div>
         <div id="SWFUpload_0_3_deleteDiv" class="remove" style="text-align: right; ">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">x</a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="progressWrapper" id="SWFUpload_0_2" style="opacity: 1; ">
      <div class="progressContainer blue">
         <a class="progressCancel" href="#" style="visibility: hidden; "> </a>
         <div class="progressName">Photo01441111.jpg</div>
         <div class="progressBarStatus">Complete.</div>
         <div class="progressBarComplete" style=""></div>
         <div id="SWFUpload_0_2_deleteDiv" class="remove" style="text-align: right; ">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">x</a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="progressWrapper" id="SWFUpload_0_3" style="opacity: 1; ">
      <div class="progressContainer blue">
         <a class="progressCancel" href="#" style="visibility: hidden; "> </a>
         <div class="progressName">Photo0145.jpg</div>
         <div class="progressBarStatus">Complete.</div>
         <div class="progressBarComplete" style=""></div>
         <div id="SWFUpload_0_3_deleteDiv" class="remove" style="text-align: right; ">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">x</a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="progressWrapper" id="SWFUpload_0_2" style="opacity: 1; ">
      <div class="progressContainer blue">
         <a class="progressCancel" href="#" style="visibility: hidden; "> </a>
         <div class="progressName">Photo0144111111.jpg</div>
         <div class="progressBarStatus">Complete.</div>
         <div class="progressBarComplete" style=""></div>
         <div id="SWFUpload_0_2_deleteDiv" class="remove" style="text-align: right; ">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">x</a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="progressWrapper" id="SWFUpload_0_3" style="opacity: 1; ">
      <div class="progressContainer blue">
         <a class="progressCancel" href="#" style="visibility: hidden; "> </a>
         <div class="progressName">Photo0145.jpg</div>
         <div class="progressBarStatus">Complete.</div>
         <div class="progressBarComplete" style=""></div>
         <div id="SWFUpload_0_3_deleteDiv" class="remove" style="text-align: right; ">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">x</a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="progressWrapper" id="SWFUpload_0_2" style="opacity: 1; ">
      <div class="progressContainer blue">
         <a class="progressCancel" href="#" style="visibility: hidden; "> </a>
         <div class="progressName">Photo0144.jpg</div>
         <div class="progressBarStatus">Complete.</div>
         <div class="progressBarComplete" style=""></div>
         <div id="SWFUpload_0_2_deleteDiv" class="remove" style="text-align: right; ">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">x</a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="progressWrapper" id="SWFUpload_0_3" style="opacity: 1; ">
      <div class="progressContainer blue">
         <a class="progressCancel" href="#" style="visibility: hidden; "> </a>
         <div class="progressName">Photo0145.jpg</div>
         <div class="progressBarStatus">Complete.</div>
         <div class="progressBarComplete" style=""></div>
         <div id="SWFUpload_0_3_deleteDiv" class="remove" style="text-align: right; ">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">x</a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="progressWrapper" id="SWFUpload_0_2" style="opacity: 1; ">
      <div class="progressContainer blue">
         <a class="progressCancel" href="#" style="visibility: hidden; "> </a>
         <div class="progressName">Photo0144.jpg</div>
         <div class="progressBarStatus">Complete.</div>
         <div class="progressBarComplete" style=""></div>
         <div id="SWFUpload_0_2_deleteDiv" class="remove" style="text-align: right; ">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">x</a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="progressWrapper" id="SWFUpload_0_3" style="opacity: 1; ">
      <div class="progressContainer blue">
         <a class="progressCancel" href="#" style="visibility: hidden; "> </a>
         <div class="progressName">Photo0145.jpg</div>
         <div class="progressBarStatus">Complete.</div>
         <div class="progressBarComplete" style=""></div>
         <div id="SWFUpload_0_3_deleteDiv" class="remove" style="text-align: right; ">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">x</a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

What I want all Divs of class "progressContainer" should be show completely in one line if you see in example some times its partly showing in one line and remaining is showing next line.

Sorry I am very new in css please help me

Comment: you need to whittle your example down. it isn't totally clear what you want and your example looks like someone threw up blue divs all over the screen.

Comment: I am stuck :( please give me a hint

Comment: You need to visually style the elements so we can *easily* see which elements belong to which `.progressContainer` element. As it is all we can see is a mess of small blue buttons on the page with no way to distinguish which should be on one line, and which on the next...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to `.progressWrapper`

```
margin-right:auto;
float:left;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the divs to `display:inline;`, set them to `display: inline-block;` and they'll start behaving. you'll need to adjust your widths etc to taste. Enjoy.

Better than floats unless you need to support old versions of IE.